# Multiple differences of opinion about transaction log autogrowth settings

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

We have a two-node SQL Server 2017 AG. There's a job that looks at autogrowth settings for our databases and makes sure they're not set to use a percentage.  For the past day, its been continually saying it's updating the settings for a particular database.  This hasn't happened before.  Upon investigation, I found sys.master_files on node 01 says the transaction log file for the database will grow in increments of 512MB, but node 02's sys.master_files says it will grow in increments of 10%  Server 02 is the primary.  On both replicas, is_percent_growth is cleared in sys.database_files for this database.  Looking at file properties in SSMS, both replicas show 512MB autogrowth, most likely because SSMS looks in sys.database_files (a guess on my part).

There haven't been any failovers on this AG.

**Questions**

1. How could there a difference of opinion between sys.master_files and sys.database_files on node 02?
2. How did the autogrowth settings for the database get out of sync between the two replicas?
3. How can I clear the is_percent_growth flag on node 02 so I don't have any more false positives?  Ideally, I'd like to do this without taking the AG offline.

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174520/sql-server-sys-master-files-vs-sys-database-files which explains the difference between sys.master_files and sys.database_files, but it doesn't explain the circumstances here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guess:

When you seed (auto or through a backup) the database, the info from sys.database_files is copied into sys.master_files on the other end (which lives in a table in the master database).

My guess is that a later change for the file properties, which is stored in (what you see though) sys.database_files is *not* reflected in sys.master_files. Perhaps some changes triggers the state to be copied into sys.master_files and some change don't? And perhaps this has been improved in later versions?

Sorry to be so vague, I don't have the environment here to test this. I would do some changes to the ldf file and see if any of those changes causes sys.master_files at the other end to be updated.

Increase the file size. Shrink it (just 1 MB). Change max size. Etc. One at a time, of course.

Comment: Tweaking the size of the log works and forced a sync between the two replicas.  Sorry  it took so long to follow up on this!